# How to get and save THIS transparent image with PHP

Tags: php, php-gd

I am trying to get a image from a URL, and then save it to the server. It is a simple task, yeah, but this image has transparency... The thing is, when i save that file to my PC or when I try to get and save it via PHP to my server, then I get the same result: the image gets all messed up with its transparency set to black. The URL of the image is:

http://cellufun.com/p/avatarimage/agb.aspx?i=Body|M04001|Shirt|M10020|

Another weird thing is my browser says the image is MIME Type image/png but I can't use imagecreatefrompng(); because I get the "image not a valid PNG" error...

Here is my code (I did try other solutions, this is what I tryed the last time):

```
<?php
$result=file_get_contents("http://cellufun.com/p/avatarimage/agb.aspx?i=Body|F04001|Shirt|F10020|Pants|MO55|");
$img = imageCreateFromstring($result);
imageAlphaBlending($img, true);
imageSaveAlpha($img, true);
imagecolortransparent($img);


header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($img);
?>
```

Oh, and I just tryed this image against the copy() function, and still get the same result... It looks like the image is smaller in size then the original image...
Just tryed this:

```
file_put_contents("files/test.png",file_get_contents($result));
```

and still not working... so it has something to do with the image itself, because whatever i try to get the data, it does not work.

Comment: Why do you use `imagegif` instead of `imagepng`?

Comment: because of this : ' I can't use imagecreatefrompng(); because I get the "image not a valid PNG" error...' as i already mentioned @Markus403 ... and I am using imagecreatefromstring()

Comment: The problem *may* be to do with the fact that your code is sending a header that says the image is a PNG, and then sends a GIF. What's a poor browser to do?

Comment: I get the same result even if I set header("Content-type: image/gif"); , or if i use imagepng() instead of imagegif() @michaelb958

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code (changes at lines 2-4):

```
<?php
$img = imageCreateFromgif("http://cellufun.com/p/avatarimage/agb.aspx?i=Body|M04001|Shirt|M10020|");
$index = imagecolorexact($img, 0, 0, 0); 
imagecolortransparent($img, $index); 

header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($img);
?>
```

It works for me although it's a little trick ;) ..and I don't know exactly why the quality is worse..

PS: The main problem I see is that the image at the url you provided is not really a png.

Comment: yeah that is the main issue here, since the mime type and file content don't really come hand in hand :( anyhow, I will try this :)

Comment: Ok i tried it and it worked! (partly) :( as you said the image quality is still terrible... any idea on how i could filter this to get a better image quality ... PS: I figured out i only needed to put 0 as index and it works even without imagecolorexact() ;)

Comment: For the bad image quality: I don't know how to correct that as as far as I see you have to use `imageCreateFromgif` which converts the image to a 256 color picture thus resulting in terrible quality.

Comment: thanks.. I solved it on my own :D it needed a small trick... the server sends a different image when you try to save it instead of viewing it... so its image (that is, server) specific :)